# Paypal SandBox Test Payment Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, sandbox

I am trying to integrate Paypal in my ASP.NET application. It works for a couple of days but now its not working. I tried to change the url to the live paypal url and it works, but if i use sandbox.paypal.com it does not work.

[Redirect Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3lGY.png)

[url attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnz2i.png)

Comment: Could you please add more details? Saying that something "does not work" is not very helpful. Is there any error message? Could you please add some code?

Comment: Added screenshot of my code. There is no error message. When I clicked the button, it redirects to the sandbox site but it just blank page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's best to paste your code into your question. Indent it by four spaces and it will render as code. Also, if you don't tell us what went wrong we really can't help you, especially with security-protected APIs like the one you're using.

Comment: Hi @MiggyTrinidad, as already mentioned, it's better to copy/paste your souce code instead of just adding a screenshot. Why? This will make other user's life easier, this way they don't have to manually type all the code.